# kafka-console-consumer ERROR Error processing message, terminating consumer process: (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$) java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: apache-kafka

Trying to see topic messages through

```
kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server (bootstrap server here) --topic (topic name here)
```

, but it seems there is an issue connecting to broker. I have zookeeper and broker up running:

```
ERROR Error processing message, terminating consumer process:  (kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:61)
        at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:349)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.memory.MemoryPool$1.tryAllocate(MemoryPool.java:30)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:102)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:452)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:402)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:674)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:576)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:560)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:280)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:251)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:242)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.awaitMetadataUpdate(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:164)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:277)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:240)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.coordinatorUnknownAndUnreadySync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:497)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:529)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1272)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1236)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1216)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$ConsumerWrapper.receive(ConsoleConsumer.scala:473)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.process(ConsoleConsumer.scala:102)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.run(ConsoleConsumer.scala:76)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer$.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala:53)
        at kafka.tools.ConsoleConsumer.main(ConsoleConsumer.scala)
Processed a total of 0 messages
```

Comment: 1) Make sure you are using a correct Kafka server address with port `9092`, for example, not Zookeeper or some other server 2) Kafka tools are not tested on Windows.